# Havok Physics : "hkQuaternionf not normalized/invalid!" when hkpWorld::stepMultithreaded()

Tags: physics-engine, havok, simd

today I want to ask a question about Havok Physics 2012.

My havok version is 2014.1.0-r1 (x86 SIMD version), and I'm using Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8.

My problem is, that once I add a rigid body to the world, the next time I call `hkpWorld::stepMultithreaded()`, it breaks in some SSE math related function and gives me this error message through my error report function.

> C:\NightlyJobs\09-07-Sun-01\Source\Common/Base/Math/Vector/Sse/hkSseVector4Util.
>   inl(307): [0x1FF88F0E] Assert: hkQuaternionf not normalized/invalid!

Here's the stack trace:

> (null)(0):'hkDefaultError::message'
>   (null)(0):'hkError::messageAssert'
>   (null)(0):'hkVector4UtilImpl::convertQuaternionToRotation'
>   (null)(0):'hkRotationf::set'
>   (null)(0):'hkTransformf::setRotation'
>   (null)(0):'hkSweptTransformUtil::calcTransAtT1'
>   (null)(0):'hkSweptTransformUtil::_stepMotionState'
>   (null)(0):'hkRigidMotionUtilApplyForcesAndStep'
>   (null)(0):'integrateJob'
>   (null)(0):'hkpMultiThreadedSimulation::processNextJob'
>   (null)(0):'hkJobQueue::processAllJobs'
>   (null)(0):'hkpWorld::stepMultithreaded'

Here's how I create and add the rigid body.
It's so basic that I didn't think there would be any room for bizarre error in it...

```
hkpSphereShape* sphere = new hkpSphereShape(radius);  // radius is 10.0f here.

hkpRigidBodyCinfo rigidBodyInfo;
rigidBodyInfo.m_shape = sphere;

m_RigidBody = new hkpRigidBody(rigidBodyInfo);

world->markForWrite();
world->addEntity(m_RigidBody);
world->unmarkForWrite();
m_RigidBody->removeReference();
```

I don't set position or rotation of the rigid body myself, so why it breaks in some quaternion related function is beyond me.

I speculated it might be one of those multithreading-related bizarre errors, so I tried changing

```
m_WorldInfo.m_simulationType = hkpWorldCinfo::SIMULATION_TYPE_MULTITHREADED;
```

to

```
m_WorldInfo.m_simulationType = hkpWorldCinfo::SIMULATION_TYPE_DISCRETE;
```

and

```
m_World->stepMultithreaded(m_JobQueue, m_CpuThreadPool, timeStep);
```

to

```
m_World->stepDeltaTime(timeStep);
```

but the problem persisted.

Do you know something that I could be doing wrong ?
Please tell me in the comments if you need to see some of my other code to help!
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I changed my havok to non-SIMD version, and the problem is gone. I tried 16-byte aligned allocations of hkpSphereShape and hkpRigidBody too (instead of just new), so I don't really understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...

It appears that if you're using the SIMD-enabled version of havok, you need to define `HK_CONFIG_SIMD`=1.

Not setting it with the SIMD-version, and setting it with the non-SIMD-version can **both** result in a crash.

**For future-visitors**:
Whichever version of havok you're using, if you encounter SSE-related crashes or errors, make sure you're not accidentally defining or not defining `HK_CONFIG_SIMD` in your code or in the project settings in your IDE.